# Can't understand Prolog line of code

Tags: prolog

I am studying for a logic test and I saw an example of Perfect number problem
There is many solutions to this however there is one that I am unsure how they have done it.

```
divisors(Number, D, L1, L2) :-
   X is Number / D,
   ( D < X -> D1 is D + 1, divsors(Number, D1, L1, L2) ; L1 = L2).
divisors(Number, D, L1, L2) :-
   0 is Number mod D, D1 is D + 1, X is Number / D,
   ( D =< X -> divisors(Number, D1, [X, D |L1], L2) ; L1 = L2).
```

Comment: did you try to use tracer?

Comment: No what is this @LuaiGhunim

Comment: Open your prolog and type in `guitracer.` then again `trace.` then execute your query, this way you can follow how it works. This will not work in windows cmd but it will work directly in prolog.

Comment: I just tried that and am still quite unsure. I was thinking more in english terms so that I could actually understand whats going on. Thank you for your help though! @LuaiGhunim

Comment: Can you provide some outputs? Or your idea to solve the problem? BTW this program has an error: you call `divsors` in third line which does not exists, maybe you would call `divisors`...

Comment: Doesn't the place you copied this code from give an explanation at all of what the predicate is generally supposed to do or what the arguments represent? Play with it to get an idea of what it does. Try queries such as `divisors(100, 2, L1, L2).`, `divisors(100, 2, [], L).`, `divisors(100, 4, [], L).`. These start to reveal the functionality. Once you understand that, then you can walk through the code. The last line with `->/2` defines termination condition for recursion. At the end of recursion, it just unifies `L1` and `L2`. This looks like an auxiliary predicate for something else.